# Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED)

Tags: python, dataframe

I've created a DataFrame and I want to use iloc for selecting few rows and columns. The below is the code I tried.

```
 data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape((4, 4)),index=['Ohio', 'Colorado', 'Utah', 'New York'],columns=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])
 data.iloc[2, [3, 0, 1]]
```

But I am facing a ValueError as below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-742c6382921b> in <module>()
----> 1 data.iloc[Integer(1),[Integer(0),Integer(2)]]

/ext/sage/sage-8.4_1804/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   1470             except (KeyError, IndexError):
   1471                 pass
-> 1472             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1473         else:
   1474             # we by definition only have the 0th axis
/ext/sage/sage-8.4_1804/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   2011     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):
   2012 
-> 2013         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
   2014         try:
   2015             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
/ext/sage/sage-8.4_1804/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
    224                 raise ValueError("Location based indexing can only have "
    225                                  "[{types}] types"
--> 226                                  .format(types=self._valid_types))
    227 
    228     def _is_nested_tuple_indexer(self, tup):
ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types
```

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: and the same code works fine for me in Py27

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, The code should select the 2nd row, [3,0,1] column values. I am using Python 2.7.15 in Jupyter Notebook

Comment: I work in Spyder and it works OK their..can't help